# Is there an R interface to Mahout?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine

Is there any package or a wrapper (something like Rweka) that can fully or partially link R and Mahout together ?

I know we can always use a `system()` call to Mahout from R, but before getting into details, I want to make sure that there is no more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Mahoot is Machine learning library in Java. SO why not to try `rJava`?

Comment: We could but WEKA is also in Java but there is Rweka package in R. I was hoping to find something similar as I have not worked much with Java.